# i18n en angular. No me funciona y no se porqué

Tags: angularjs, i18n

¡Hola!

Estoy un poquito desesperada.

Llevo dos días intentado hacer uso de i18n en mi proyecto de angular.

He leido y visto varios videos. He siguido paso a paso en de la pagina de angular pero no me funciona.

Los pasos que seguí fue:

- instalar ng add @angular/localize
- en mi archivo angular.json añadí lo necesario:

  ```
   {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
      "version": 1,
      "newProjectRoot": "projects",
      "projects": {
        "maleteo": {
          "i18n": {
            "sourceLocale": "es-ES",
            "locales": {"en-US": "src/locale/messages en.xlf"}
          },
          "projectType": "application",
          "schematics": {},
          "root": "",
    ......
  ```
- Seguí añadiendo al angular.json lo necesario:

  ........

  ```
  "projectType": "application",
  "schematics": {},
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      "options": {
        "localize": ["en-US"],

    "outputPath": "dist/maleteo",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "browser": "src/main.ts",
  ```

  ............
- Luego añadí la etiqueta i18n a los textos que quiero traducir.
  Y así en varios html de mi proyecto.
- El siguiente paso era poner en mi app.component.ts lo siguiente:

  constructor(private titleService:Title) { this.titleService.setTitle($localize`{this.title}`);}
- Después puse en consola ng extract-i18n --output-path src/locale, creando así el archivo messages.xlf, y creando una copia cambiando el nombre a messages.en.xlf. En dicho archivo hice todas las traducciones usando el target con la traducción, debajo de source y el texto a traducir.

Ya al darle a ng serve no me deja porque me da errores, tipo Property 'title' does not exist on type 'LandingPageComponent'.ts(2339)
any

No se que pasa con el X [ERROR] TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type 'LandingPageComponent'. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
src/app/pages/landing-page/landing-page.component.ts:19:49:
  19 │     this.titleService.setTitle($localize`${ this.title}`);
```

No tengo ni idea que hacer... chatGPT me dice esto: Parece que estás intentando acceder a la propiedad title en un objeto de tipo LandingPageComponent, pero TypeScript te está dando un error porque no reconoce esa propiedad en ese tipo. Para solucionar este problema, debes asegurarte de que la propiedad title esté definida en tu clase LandingPageComponent.

Pero en el tutorial de angular no me dice nada de añadir lo que me dice...

AYUDA POR FAVOR!!

Esto es lo que tengo en mi componente, donde supongo que está el error:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterLink],
  templateUrl: './landing-page.component.html',
  styleUrl: './landing-page.component.css'
})
export class LandingPageComponent implements OnInit { showModal = false;
  showModal2 = false;
  title: string = 'maleteo';

  constructor(private titleService:Title) {
    this.titleService.setTitle($localize`${ this.title}`);
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.showModal = true;
    }, 2000);
  }

  closeModal(id:string) {
    if (id === 'showModal' ){

      this.showModal = false;
      this.showModal2 = true;

    }else{
      this.showModal2 = false;
    }
  };
}



         ╵
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega lo que tienes en ese componente :D

Comment: Las rutas no deberían contener espacios, suelen dar problemas...